# Integration of error function

Tags: integration

How to integrate:
$$\int \mathrm{erf}\left(\dfrac a{\sqrt{2T}}+b\sqrt{\dfrac T2}\right)\,\mathrm dT?$$
I think I should take integral and replace some parts with other error functions

Wolfram Alpha shows it like:
[WA solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aWwN.jpg)
But how do they do it?
If my domain is reals, can I replace $$\sqrt{a^2}$$ with absolute value of a?

Comment: Chances are low that you can find a closed-form solution.

Comment: To the last question: if $a \geq 0$ then yes, otherwise it should be $|a|$